# Rails: rendering different js templates for different AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails app with Movies#index page. I make AJAX requests to this action on 2 occasions:

1. When I'm loading more @movies
2. When I'm filtering @movies

Depending on which of those I want, I'd like to render a different js file (instead of index.js.erb for both).

What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      if (user_is_filtering)
        format.js { render :template => "movies/available.js.erb" }
      else
        format.js { render :template => "movies/load_more.js.erb" }
      end
    end
```

Not sure if this is best practice, but it works.